# Filter table in a function using a table valued parameter

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

I have a table-valued function that uses a parameter to filter a table and returns the results:

```
drop table if exists mytbl;
create table mytbl (i int);
insert into mytbl (i) values (1),(2),(3);

CREATE FUNCTION filterer(
    _filter int
)
RETURNS TABLE(i_ret int)
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
AS $BODY$
BEGIN
    RETURN  QUERY   SELECT  i 
                    FROM    mytbl
                    WHERE   i = _filter;
END;
$BODY$;
select * from filterer(1);
```

it returns:

[image]

So far so good. However what I really want to do is filter on a list of values rather than just one. I figured the way to do it is create a table-valued parameter using a type that I define using CREATE TYPE, but I can't get it working. Here's what I have so far:

```
drop table if exists mytbl;
create table mytbl (i int);
DO $$
BEGIN
    IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT   * FROM  pg_type t WHERE t.typname = 'tp') THEN
        CREATE TYPE tp AS (i int);
    END IF;
END$$;
insert into mytbl (i) values (1),(2),(3);
DROP FUNCTION public.filterer(tp);
CREATE FUNCTION filterer(
    _filter tp
)
RETURNS TABLE(i_ret int)
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
AS $BODY$
BEGIN
    RETURN  QUERY   SELECT  i 
                    FROM    mytbl
                    WHERE   i IN (_filter);
END;
$BODY$;

select * from filterer(1);
```

When I run that code it fails with:

> ERROR:  function filterer(integer) does not exist LINE 23: select *
>   from filterer(1);

How do I declare a variable of type `tp` and pass it into my function?

Comment: There is no such thing as a "table valued function" in Postgres. Do you mean a "set returning function"?

Comment: I guess so. Apologies, I'm not aware of the correct terminology. I have a heritage in SQL Server and there they're called tabled-valued functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[working example](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/gpP7jAzFh7rq3o9732ibDL/0)

Two things here:

```
 WHERE   i IN (_filter);
```

should be replaced with

```
 WHERE   row(i) IN (_filter);
```

and calling:

```
select * from filterer(row(1));
```

I  assume the question is purely academic, as I can't see any use of such type?..

```
CREATE TYPE tp AS (i int);
```

Comment: That's great, thank you. And thanks for making me aware of dbfiddle. Now I want to pass multiple values into the function, how can I do that? (And yes, this example is purely for demo purposes, the real problem I'm trying to solve is much more complicated)

Comment: no worries, please don't forget to upvote and/or accept the answer